# Filter one list using other list in fastest way?

Tags: javascript, java, kotlin, dart

I have one list of objects of Food with fields name and price.
I have other list of objects of Category with fields `food_name` and its `category_name`.

Now, I want to filter the first list according to the `category_name` in the second list. How can I do it in fastest way possible?

I am tagging few languages because I just need the filtering logic on any language.

For e.g. in Dart

```
List<Food> foods = [Food(name: 'Mango', price: 50), Food(name: 'Cucumber', price: 100)];
List<Category> categories = [Category(name: 'Fruits', foodName: 'Mango'), Category(name: 'Vegetables', foodName: 'Cucumber')  ];
```

I want to filter the list of foods according to category name from second list in fastest way possible.

Comment: don't use a `List` to begin with, a hash based collection should perform better

Comment: You may have the data _written down_ in a list, but I bet it doesn't _behave_ like a list.  For one thing, in a list the order is significant; and for another, a list allows duplicate items (and certainly items with a duplicate field) — I expect neither are true here.  It's always worth looking at how your data behaves, to see what hidden assumptions you're making about its structure — and then trying to represent them in the code.  As one answer says, it looks like a least one of those is really a map.  (And, luckily, that leads on to more efficient code.)

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two lists this will cost you O(n^2) time, you should instead consider using a map structure. In Kotlin this can be done as

```
val map = foodList.associateBy { it.name }
val result = mutableListOf<Food>()
categoryList.forEach {
    if(map.containsKey(it.foodName)) { result.add(map[it.foodName]) }
}
```